# EPL Esper query use historical time stored in event's property instead of publish time

Tags: esper, epl, nesper

Let's say that I have a simple object:

```
public class StockTick{
    private String symbol;
    private decimal price;
    private Date date;
    private int unixTimestamp
}
```

How should I modify following query to use StockTick.date or StockTick.unixTimestamp to agregate within .win:time() window?

```
select avg(price) from StockTick.win:time(30 sec) where symbol='IBM'
```

Comment: This is better: select avg(price) from StockTick(symbol='IBM').win:time(30 sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If events are already ordered by unix timestamp, you don't need to modify the query. Just do this for each event:

```
runtime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(unixTimestamp));
runtime.sendEvent(stockTickEvent);
```

This above code uses the external time so disable the default internal system time. For completely unordered or unstaged events, don't use a time window at all and instead think about how a group-by would look like.

Comment: Is there some recommedned approach when working in multithreaded environment? This doesn't seem quite atomic

Comment: Also what would happen if this approach would be used to unordered items?

Comment: Time always moves forward. The query would be different and would probably use group-by for unordered. For multithreaded we have used one thread that moves time forward and multiple threads to send events that don't send time.

Comment: Unordered events can also be staged and reordered of course.

Comment: Just a quick note that CurrentTimeEvent "jumps" forward (skipping any times in between), while CurrentTimeSpanEvent kind of rolls the time forward. A statement with "output every 5 seconds" for example will not produce the intermediate events with TimeEvent, but will do so with TimeSpanEvent.